# Error using discord bot on my ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I have a discord bot, on my premises (Windows 10) it works correctly, but on the server (Ubuntu Server 20) it gives me the following error.

The error occurs when I receive a chat message from the server, that is, for example, on my computer, I would read the message and reply to it, on the server, I get the error.

```js
(node:657201) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).flatMap is not a function
    at Promise.all.events.map (/root/discordbot/node_modules/@typeit/src/logic/metadatas/MetadataStorage.ts:155:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:657201) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:657201) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`
```

It's the same project, the same everything, I don't know what can happen.

Comment: Are you trying to send an embedded massage with discord.js?

Comment: What's the Node version in the Ubuntu machine? Based on [this](https://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-es2019-flat-flatmap-catch.html#:~:text=The%20flat()%20and%20flatMap,js%2011.), you need Node >= 11

Comment: Show your code and `node -v`

Comment: @Owl I have  v10.19.0

Comment: @Garto Yes, but I think the crash is trying to read the message

Comment: @NurioFernández the version is v10.19.0

Comment: That seems to be the problem, try updating to 11+

Comment: @Owl I cant update, my ubuntu says its the last version.
```apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.flat()` and `.flatMap` are only available on Node >= 11

Seems like you are using Node 10, try upgrading your Node to version 11+

You can use nvm, install by running this command

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash`

or

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash`

then run `nvm install node`,
this will install latest node version, you can also specify the version like this
`nvm install 12.16.3`

then use the version, to use the latest version, run `nvm use node`
or to use specific installed version, run `nvm install 12.16.3`

Then verify your node version by running `node -v`